# linkage error in spring web services while deploying in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, websphere

I have using Spring web services in my project (Based on spring cloud) and my application server is webSphere 8.5.5.13. I am trying to deploy my application in webSphere and getting Linkage error.

```
loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/xml/xpath/XPath.setNamespaceContext(Ljavax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext;)V" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@2d2b7c15" of class "org/springframework/xml/xpath/Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@d0e18365" of class "javax/xml/xpath/XPath" have different types for the method signature
```

So i have added

```
  @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
                System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory", "org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionFactory");
        return builder.sources(app.class);
    }
```

But no luck. Any suggestions please

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/faq.html#saaj-websphere

Comment: I saw it but i can't understood. Please do needful

Comment: I think it means that the version of those classes in WebSphere are different than the version you're wanting to use. Thus, you have to use one of those techniques to make WebSphere let your app use your provided version instead of its own version.

Comment: i also have this problem  how i can select  mi inplemantacion over container jar